# QML TreeView itemDelegate not indicating isSelected

Tags: qml, treeview, selected

I have created a simple TreeView in QML, with several levels of nesting.  I have also created an "itemDelegate" and a "rowDelegate"; both of which switch background color between red/black bound to their respective isSelected.

When I click on an item the ROW color changes, but the item does not.  I confirmed the itemFlag for each item includes ItemsIsSelectable and ItemIsEnabled (default).

My itemDelegate contains:

```
  Rectangle {
                color: styleData.isSelected ? "red" : "black"
```

I added a selection to the treeview:

```
  ItemSelectionModel {
       id: treeViewSelectionModel
       objectName: "treeViewSelectionModel"
       model: treemodel
       onCurrentChanged:{console.log("Selection - current changed from ",previous, " to ", current)}
   }
```

Which correctly prints out the new/previous selection.  So it appears the item is being selected, but not changing color. Can someone explain why?

Comment: From what you have posted of your Rectangle it is not possible to tell but do you set it's size / anchors?

Comment: According to [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.11/qml-qtquick-controls-tableview.html#itemDelegate-prop) you should use `styleData.selected` not `styleData.isSelected`

Comment: @Maxim - that was it!  Seems QML is not consistent with naming methods for styleData.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QQC1 is not consistant, so item uses styleData.selected while row uses styleData.isSelected

(as noted by Maxim)